# Creating an array with video IDs and Titles

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops

I am trying create a loop that would create a video thumbnail that contains the video title.

I currently have the function set up to get the IDs and I can get the loop to generate the thumbnail and link, how would I write out the array or function to include the title?

This is my current layout.

```
var Ids = "id1,id2,id3";

 if (typeof Ids === 'undefined') { Ids = ""; }
 var vIds = Ids.split(",");

$.each(vIds, function(index,value) {

 $('.vrow').append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-link col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6 vid vid'+index+'"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/'+value+'/mqdefault.jpg" alt="" /><span><i class="fa fa-play"></i></span></button>');
 });
```

I did try to use a separate array for the title, but it only created more loops and it did not render the YT ID.

Would it be possible to use the array for both the ID and Title? If so, how would I be able to map title value? Would this be considered as a *multidimensional array*?

```
var Ids = "id1,title1,id2,title2";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the updates and answers. I took your considerations, and I also had to consider something, I need the code to work for people who don't work with code at all times, therefore must reduce the risk of breakage and UI.

I decided to make a variable to each ID and Title, and then create an array via Split. All you would have to do is paste your ID/title and separate by a comma.

```
var Ids = '';
var Titles = '';

if (typeof Ids === 'undefined') { Ids = ""; }
if (typeof Titles === 'undefined') { Titles = ""; }
var vIds = Ids.split(",");
var Vtls = Titles.split(",");
```

Then I created a loop to create the buttons. This perfectly set up the thumbnails, video ID to be played and added the subtitle.

```
$.each(vIds, function(index,value) {
 //console.log(index,value);
 
 //first video gets set as featured
 $('iframe').attr('src','https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+vIds[0]);
 $('h3').text(Vtls[0]);

//create video button
  $('.vrow').append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-link col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6 vid vid'+index+'"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/'+value+'/mqdefault.jpg" alt="" /><span><i class="fa fa-play"></i></span><span class="vtitle">'+Vtls[index]+'</span></button>');
  
//create video swap function
 $('button.vid'+index).click(function() { 
   $('iframe').attr('src','https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+value);
   $('h3').text(Vtls[index]);     
});
  
//if no videos, remove video div
if (vIds.length < 1) { $('.videos-section-inner').remove(); }
if (vIds.length === 1) { $('button.vid'+index).remove(); }
  
  //end loop
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the IDs must not be spaced with  , otherwise you'll get  `id2` instead of `id2`:

```
var Ids = "id1,id2,id3";
```

To insert also the title you can use another different character as delimiter, for example:

```
var iDsWithTitle = "id1|title1,id2|title2,id3|title3";
```

Be aware that the title may contains `,`, so you should chose another delimiter such as `|`.

A better method is by using a json string to store those data and then convert it to an object that you'll cycle.

Comment: Thanks! my code has the IDs conjoined. I shouldve made that look more exact.

From the iDsWithTitle var, how would I map the title?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array objects like below. Then each object would contain the video's information. Then simply loop through the array and reference the video's information.

```js
let videos = [
{"id": "id1","title": "Video Title 1"},
{"id": "id2","title": "Video Title 2"},
{"id": "id3","title": "Video Title 3"},
{"id": "id4","title": "Video Title 4"}
];

$.each(videos, function(index,video) {
  $('.vrow').append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-link col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6 vid vid' + video.id + '"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/' + video.id + '/mqdefault.jpg" alt="" /><span><i class="fa fa-play"></i></span></button>');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vrow"></div>
```